# LSTM time-series forecasting with datasets as multiple independent CSV files

Tags: csv, pytorch, time-series, lstm, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to train an LSTM model that can predict/forecast one target using 5 features as network input. My datasets are in CSV files; each file represents an independent scenario that starts from t = 0 s to t = 100 s with a time step of 1 s; which means I cannot stack them together sequentially. For example, let’s say I have 50 CSV files, then each file will have 100 rows (representing the time steps) with a total of 6 columns (5 features + 1 target). In other words, each file is a 2-D matrix of size (100 * 6).

My goal is to use an LSTM to receive a sequence of the 5 features (e.g., seq_length=3) as input and predict/forecast one future value of the target at a time starting from t = 0 to t = 100. I am going to split the 50 datasets into training, validation, and testing sets. My questions are:

1. How can I efficiently create Pytorch DataSet and DataLoader for the training sets?
2. Is it reasonable to create a Pytorch DataSet and DataLoader for each training file and then loop
   through all train files one at a time? Accumulating the loss after each training file, then taking            the average once all training files have been used?
3. Since all my data are time-series data (functions of time), should I or should I not use
   shuffle=True when using DataLoader?

I am a beginner in ML and have a basic background in such topics. If my questions are unclear or need clarification, please let me know. Any feedback is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

I have tried creating a seperate Pytorch Dataset and DataLoader (as in Q-02) for each training file but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.